# Can grep show context, but not a full line?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have a file with several very long lines. I want to grep for a string which may occur several times in the file, including possibly more than once on the one line.

```
$ cat 2014-11-03.json | grep 218
```

This produces unreadable output. There's just too much of it.

```
$ cat 2014-11-03.json | grep -o 218
```

This cuts down too much. It shows only the matched pattern without any context.

Basically, I want output like

```
... <category_id>218</category_id> ...
```

(Yes, this is XML, but I don’t want to parse XML. I just want to output the matched string with a few characters either side of it. Just a few characters, not the whole line.)

Grep seems to have options to show *only* the matched string, or the matched string in the context of its full line (the default behaviour), or the matched string in the context of a few lines before and after, but I cannot find an option to show the matched string in the context of a few characters before and after.

```
$ cat 2014-11-03.json | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 218
```

That’s not ideal: it works so long as the file in question has spaces in roughly the right places. It worked for me this time, but there’s no guarantee it would again.

Comment: Does [Grep characters before and after match?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8101701) help?

Comment: I find that using a filter such as `sed <XMLfile 's/></>\n</g' | grep ...` is very helpful when handling XML files without new-lines.

Comment: Related: [How to make grep output fit screen's width of characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423312/80216)

Answer (score 24):

This question is old, but since I stumbled on it while looking for a way to grep only part of a line, here goes:

A workaround is to enable the option 'only-matching' and then to use RegExp's power to grep a bit more than your text:

```
grep -o ".\{0,50\}WHAT_I_M_SEARCHING.\{0,50\}" ./filepath
```

Of course, if you use color highlighting, you can always grep again to only color the real match:

```
grep -o ".\{0,50\}WHAT_I_M_SEARCHING.\{0,50\}"  ./filepath | grep "WHAT_I_M_SEARCHING"
```

Note:

- this might not return all expected results if you have several matches per line: the .{0,50} might match part of the following match and thus prevent the matching.
- This regex is slow. Very slow. (see comments for possible solution)

Comment: One option to accelerate it would be to run it after grepping for lines containing WHAT_I_M_SEARCHING to reduce the scope.

Comment: Good idea indeed

Comment: Great! I've used this for searching a folder: `export SEARCH=needle; grep -Rl $SEARCH haystack/ | xargs grep -o ".\{0,50\}$SEARCH.\{0,50\}" | grep $SEARCH`.

Comment: @odinho-Velmont Works great! However I noticed that in the case that the first grep returns only one file, the second grep needs an explicit `-H` if you want the filename in the final result despite being the default. That makes it `export SEARCH=needle; grep -Rl $SEARCH haystack/ | xargs grep -oH ".\{0,50\}$SEARCH.\{0,50\}" | grep $SEARCH`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use:

```
grep -o -P '.{0,50}search_string.{0,50}' 2014-11-03.json | grep 'search_string'
```

This will give you 50 characters before and after `search_string` with highlighting.

Comment: `cat` is useless here.

Comment: @Toto Thx for the feedback, I've updatet the answer with command without use of cat.

Answer (score 2):

Bet way I know to display json in a pretty format is using pjson. After the format, your can add your grep command.

```
$ echo '{"test1":"t1","test2":"t2"}' | pjson
{
   "test1": "t1",
   "test2": "t2"
}
```

Install it with `pip`:

```
pip install pjson
```

and then, pipe any json content to `pjson`.

Comment: What I've got is weirdly XML wrapped within JSON. It's very long XML strings, so even a JSON formatter would probably leave very long lines. I think a more generic solution, not caring what format the log file is in, would suit better. (Besides, despite the `.json` extension, it's not true JSON: each line is an independent JSON document.)

Comment: This helped me, way to think outside the box, thanks!