# How to grep and get only matching string?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

*Feel free to change the title as it does not match my question 100%*

I have something like this in a file:

```
junk
long_string "/I/want/this/$code/$name" long_string
junk
```

Clarifying the example:

- The **/I/want/this/** part is always the same
- **$code** and **$name** are dynamic and different for each string
- Inside **long_string** there can be more **/I/want/this/$code/$name** strings and I would like to get all of them.
- The quotation marks (this => **"**) are present in every **/I/want/this/$code/$name** string.

So far I've tried...

`grep -w "/I/want/this/*" file` # outputs long_string
`grep -o "/I/want/this/*" file` # outputs /I/want/this/

Would like to avoid using the solution of getting only x extra characters before and/or after

Comment: Your second command is nearly right, but there are two issues: the quotes are parsed out by `bash` and `grep` doesn't see them; and the wild-card `*` is different between `grep` and `bash`: the `*` in `bash` is equivalent to `.*` in `grep`. so what you need is `grep -o '"/I/want/this/.*"'`

Comment: @AFH that's true but executing it returns *long_ass_string*

Comment: It didn't for me: `echo 'long_ass_string "/I/want/this/$code/$name" long_ass_string'|grep -o '"/I/want/this/.*"'` returns `"/I/want/this/$code/$name"`.

Comment: Check this related question: https://superuser.com/questions/836183/can-grep-show-context-but-not-a-full-line

Answer (score 8):

I would go with grepping all strings and then sort it out with a second grep, e.g.:

```
grep -o '"[^"]*"' file
```

Output:

```
"/I/want/this/$code/$name"
```

#### Comment on your use of regular expressions

This expression `/I/want/this/*` matches `/I/want/this` and then zero or more slash characters, you probably meant: `/I/want/this/.*` which matches `/I/want/this/` and zero or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you well you want to get ridd off the first $code and $name variable in each line.
You can pipe your result to cut for that.
Following your example:

```
grep "/I/want/this/" myfile.txt | cut -d '/' -f 1-4,7-
```

with `-d` you define the delimiter ( the symbol `/` for instance) and with `-f` you indicate the field to grab.
In this case from delimiter 1 to 4 (`/I/want/this/` ) and all the fields that come after the seventh delimiter (that is done with argument `7-`)
Like this you takes away `/$code/$name` which are between 4th and 7th delimiter in all lines that match the defined regular expression.

```
echo "/I/want/this/NOT/THAT/and/everythingelse" | grep "/I/want/this/" | cut -d '/' -f 1-4,7- 
/I/want/this/and/everythingelse
```

Comment: you can just grep "/I/want/this/" myfile.txt . Cat abuse isn't necessary.

Comment: No, I can not cut the result as there can be more than one matching string in the *long_ass_string* so using cut would give me just the first one

Comment: I think i don't undesrtand what you realy want to do... Otherwise the command take everything after $name even if the regular expression is present several times` echo "/I/want/this/NOT/THAT/and/everythingelse/even/if/I/want/this/is/here/again" | grep "/I/want/this/" | cut -d '/' -f 1-4,7-` The result is `/I/want/this/and/everythingelse/even/if/I/want/this/is/here/again` No matter how many occurrences you have, the entire line is grabbed with one or two matches.