# Mining plain text

Tags: search, grep, plaintext

(original title: grep in terms of paragraphs not lines)

This question is motived by `fzf`, which allows me to locate a certain file in my huge file system *fuzzily and incrementally*, providing a very very fast searching experience (see tons of cute gifs in this [article](https://medium.com/@sidneyliebrand/how-fzf-and-ripgrep-improved-my-workflow-61c7ca212861)).

What I have in mind is to do similar things over my notes. I have bunch of fleeting notes, diaries, memos.. etc, in plain-text format. For [readability](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability), each line contains no more than 72 characters. This makes my note hard to be searched upon, based on my naive knowledge about existing searching tools like `grep`, `ripgrep`..

Now, you can show ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)/[less](https://superuser.com/questions/836183/can-grep-show-context-but-not-a-full-line)) context around a matched pattern , but that's not what I'm asking for. Here I include an example to make it more precise.

```
1  Victim mentality is an acquired personality trait in which a person
2  tends to recognize or consider themselves as a victim of the negative
3  actions of others, and to behave as if this were the case in the face
4  of contrary evidence of such circumstances. Victim mentality depends
5  on clear thought processes and attribution.
6
7  (from wikipedia: Victim mentality)
```

Say I took this note half year before, and I knew it's somewhere in my file system. As usual, we cannot recite the exact words, but **we remember the context**! `grep`ing texts like `personality`, `clear thought`, or `victim` over my file system will likely give me **too** many relevant things for me to really narrow down.

There should be a tool (existing or not) that helps search texts like this. [Our old notes (in plain text) will be much more valuable](https://writingcooperative.com/zettelkasten-how-one-german-scholar-was-so-freakishly-productive-997e4e0ca125). Is there a way to do it with our good old friend `grep` and its relatives? Or are there other ways that would work? Any opinion is highly appreciated too.

Comment: I don't know how you expect to find files if you don't know anything else than a word in it and your assume that with just that word you will get way to many results? `grep` will only look for that. `find` might include meta information. Whatever information you want to use has to be either part of the meta information or part of the file. Including tags and such in your file is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the (searching) process into smaller parts.

First we need to get list of files within you want to search, like in current directory (`.`) all files with txt-extension (`-name "*.txt"`) which are certainly files (`-type f`):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f
```

This result is possible to use as input to `grep` to find `something` inside those files, including line number and filename into output, ignoring case (`-nHi`), `+` in the end makes sure, that all files are grepped in one execution (not one at time):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec grep -nHi 'something' {} +
```

If file count is too big (>`$ARG_MAX`), you should replace **`+`** with `\;`.

Output of previous command is something like:

```
./some/dir/somewhere/songs.txt:128:But had me believing it was always something that I'd done
./some/dir/somewhere/songs.txt:883:Was never something I pursued
./some/dir/somewhere/songs.txt:2905:I know something about love 
./some/dir/somewhere/songs_other.txt:11780:will come across something like this:  F (Dshape).
```

So, if you split those lines by `:` you get 3 components: filename, line number where match was found and line itself.

Now, if you keep this information for every matched file, you can search for next terms and sum matching distance to find files, where searched terms are nearest.

For your example text if you search your 3 terms (`personality`, `clear thought`, `victim`) you got corresponding line numbers as 1, 5 and 2, so distance for this file is (originating from first term)

```
abs(1-5) + abs(1-2) = 5
```

So you can then sort files depending containing all terms and having them nearest in that file.

Of course, this is not whole picture, for example some files are containing same term multiple times and the this algorithm has to make some decisions how to compute distances, but I think above is something to start.

Comment: I see. It seems implementable. What I need essentially seems to be an algorithm of assigning weight that meets "my need", or a clever algorithm that meet most of people's need.

Comment: @Student There are tools implementing it, of course, but those seemed too big to kill a fly. But maybe not. If you don't want create it yourself, you could look for full text search, Wikipedia lists a few free tools too, for example Postgresql corresponding tools or Elasticsearch are great.

Comment: It's valuable to know those products. I will look into them!

Answer (score 0):

A simple Perl one-liner can do the job. The following will print the filename followed by "found" if all the keywords (i.e. `personality` and `clear thought` and `victim` are present in the file.)

```
perl -0777 -ane 'print "$ARGV: found\n" if /^(?=.*personality)(?=.*clear thought)(?=.*victim)/s' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
file.txt: found
```

**Explanation:**

```
-0777       # slurp mode
-ane        # read the file ans execute the following
print "$ARGV: found\n"      # print,$ARGV contains the current filename
if                          # if
  /                         # regex delimiter
    ^                       # begining of file
      (?=.*personality)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have "personality"
      (?=.*clear thought)   # positive lookahead, make sure we have "clear thought"
      (?=.*victim)          # positive lookahead, make sure we have "victim"
  /s                        # regex delimiter, s = dot matches newline
```

If you want to search in all txt files, use `perl ......  *.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. but this is not what I was asking for.. I'd like a more fuzzy+incremental searching tool.

Comment: @Student: Sorry but I don't get you. Don't you want to find all files that contain a set of keywords?

Comment: Not just that. I wish I could describe it more vividly, but nothing on top of my mind surpass the beautiful GIFs in this [article](https://medium.com/@sidneyliebrand/how-fzf-and-ripgrep-improved-my-workflow-61c7ca212861).